Body obj always take on the color of lower garment (Python API)
So, basically I have a SMPL body mesh(without texture cordinates), a shirt garment mesh(with texture cordinates) and a pant garment mesh(with texture cordinates). Using blender I load the load first lower garment in the scene and attach the texture image for it to it, then the same for the upper garment and then load the body mesh in the scene and export the obj file. BUt the exported obj file has the color of the pant garment. I don't know whats causing this. Assigning a new material with diffuse color doesn't work. It works when the diffuse color is set to (0,0,0) but when I increase it, its goes back to the color of the garment.
import bpy
import sys
import os
import argparse

class Renderer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_args()
        self.setup_scene()
        self.setup_objects()

    def get_args(self):
        # Parse arguments
        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("--up_mesh", type=str, help="location of upper mesh")
        ap.add_argument("--up_text", type=str, help="location of upper texture")

        ap.add_argument("--low_mesh", type=str, help="location of lower mesh")
        ap.add_argument("--low_text", type=str, help="location of lower texture")

        ap.add_argument("--body_mesh", type=str, help="location of body mesh")

        ap.add_argument("--output_path", type=str, help="Location to export the combined object")

        # Extract arguments passed to Blender
        argv = sys.argv[sys.argv.index("--") + 1:]
        self.args = ap.parse_args(argv)

    def setup_scene(self):
        # Setup scene settings
        bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
        bpy.context.scene.render.use_border = False
        bpy.context.scene.render.alpha_mode = 'TRANSPARENT'
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

    def insert_object(self, gar_loc, tex_loc, scale, body_bool):
        # Import object
        bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=gar_loc)
        obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        obj_object.scale = (scale, scale, scale)
        
        # If it's the body mesh, preserve vertex colors
        if body_bool:
            if obj_object.data.vertex_colors:
                print("in true")
                # If vertex colors are defined, use them
                mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='body_material')
                mat.use_vertex_color_paint = True
                obj_object.data.materials.append(mat)
            else:
                print("in false")
                # If vertex colors are not defined, create a new material
                mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='body_material')
                mat.diffuse_color = (1, 1, 1)  # Light gray color
                obj_object.data.materials.append(mat)
        else:
            # Add texture if provided and not a body mesh
            if tex_loc:
                img = bpy.data.images.load(tex_loc)
                cTex = bpy.data.textures.new('Texture', type='IMAGE')
                cTex.image = img
                mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='object')
                mtex = mat.texture_slots.add()
                mtex.texture = cTex
                mat.specular_color = (1, 1, 1)
                mat.use_shadeless = True
                obj_object.data.materials.append(mat)









    def setup_objects(self):
        # Insert upper, lower, and body meshes
        self.insert_object(self.args.low_mesh, self.args.low_text, 4.0, body_bool=False)
        self.insert_object(self.args.up_mesh, self.args.up_text, 4.0, body_bool=False)
        self.insert_object(self.args.body_mesh, None, 4.0, body_bool=True)
        
       

    def run(self):
        # Export combined object
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=self.args.output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    renderer = Renderer()
    renderer.run()

Orignal SMPL Body Mesh

Blender Output Mesh

I don't know whats causing this. Any help would be appreciated!
